# How to set dynamic chunk size for a step with MutliResoucrItemReader?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using *MultiResourceItemReader* which takes the Resource Array. I want set the chunk size dynamically based on number of lines in each resource.

Below is the configured step in the configuration file.

```
@Bean
public Step processStep(){
return stepBuilderFactory.get("processStep").<itempojo,itempojo>chunk(3) //I dont want to set fixed chunk  here
  .reader(multiResourceItemReader())
  .processor(processor())
  .writer(writer())
  .listener(readerListener())
  .build();

/** MulitResource Item Reader */

public MultiResourceItemReader<ItemPojo> multiResourceItemReader(){
MultiResourceItemReader<ItemPojo> itemreader = new 
MultiResourceItemReader();
itemreader.setResources(resources);
itemreader.setDelegate(flatFileReader());
}
```

Could any one suggest how can I approach dynamic chunk size, in the case of MultiResourceItemReader. please let me know incase any information required thankyou.

Comment: Does you mean you want to change the chunk size according to the current resource at runtime while the step is running?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Yes exactly, in the JobExecution Listener (at before Item) setting the Resources Array dynamically and passing to the MultiResourceItem Reader. to give more inputs I have update the question with configured Reader.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can set the chunk size dynamically at runtime *before* the step is executed (based on a job parameter or an attribute from the execution context by using the late-binding technique), but *not after* it has been started.